# Multidimensional array sort by another array value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort out the sequence of individual array. How to use my another array list?

There is a predefined array:

```
$sortOrder = array("Night","Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner","Lying");
```

And this is it my original array content:

```
Array
(
    [Normal] => Array
        (
        [Dinner] => Array
            (
                [avgtime] => 17,06
                [avg] => 5.24
            )

        [Breakfast] => Array
            (
                [avgtime] => 04,25
                [avg] => 4.96
            )

        [Lying] => Array
            (
                [avgtime] => 14,49
                [avg] => 4.7
            )

        [Lunch] => Array
            (
                [avgtime] => 09,53
                [avg] => 5.26
            )

        [Night] => Array
            (
                [avgtime] => 00,00
                [avg] => 4.4
            )

    )

[High] => Array
    (
        [Dinner] => Array
            (
                [avg] => 9
                [avgtime] => 17,35
            )

    )

[Low] => Array
    (
        [Night] => Array
            (
                [avg] => 3.5
                [avgtime] => 02,35
            )

        [Breakfast] => Array
            (
                [avg] => 3.8
                [avgtime] => 07,12
            )
    )
)
```

How can I order placed based on the list? Please help me, and thanks so much!

Comment: `$arr["normal"] = array_replace($sortOrder, $arr["normal"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve more efficient key searching let's use static arrays in the comparison function:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
  uksort($arr[$key], function($a, $b) {
    static $sortOrder = ['Night', 'Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner', 'Lying'];

    static $order;
    if (!isset($order)) {
      $order = array_flip($sortOrder);
    }

    $value = 0;
    if (array_key_exists($a, $order) && array_key_exists($b, $order)) {
      $value = ($order[$a] > $order[$b] ? 1 : -1);
    }
    return $value;
  });
}
```

Comment: You helped a lot! I stayed array_flip step... :)

Answer (score 0):

solution using [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php),

```
$temp = array ('Lunch'=>'3', 'Lying' => '5', 'Night' => '1', 'Dinner' => '4', 'Breakfast' => '2');

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $sortOrder = array("Night","Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner","Lying");
    $pos1 =  array_search($a, $sortOrder);
    $pos2 =  array_search($b, $sortOrder);
    if (pos1 == pos2) return 0;
    return ($pos1 > $pos2)? 1:-1;
}

uksort($temp, 'cmp');

// output: Array ( [Night] => 1 [Breakfast] => 2 [Lunch] => 3 [Dinner] => 4 [Lying] => 5 )
```